# how to make ajax works on subdomains

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a plugin on my wordpress site and this plugin is using ajax to send the information to database

the problem is that i have subdomains on some pages on my website " xxx.xyn.com "

and the ajax is working fine on the main domain xyn.com but it's not working on subdomains so how can i make it work on subdomains too ?

here is the code :

```
http_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
http_req.onreadystatechange = function() 
{eemail_submitresult(es_widget_form)};  // Passing the form to the submit request
http_req.open('POST', url, true);
http_req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http_req.send(parameters);
```

so how can i make it works ?

and if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is the solution can you tell me how to allow it ?

is it codes to add in javascript, php, htaccess or apache ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean, you are visiting a page of url `xxx.xyn.com`, and it fetches XHR data from `xyn.com` right?

In that case you will need to add the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header in the response from xyn.com. For more information, see the link above.

Comment: thank you for your answer .. can you tell me how to allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin and where to add these codes ? is it in javascript, php, htaccess or apache

Comment: i tried to add Header add ( Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" )
in htaccsess
but it didn't work ?

Comment: Either add it from php or apache (or htaccess) should work fine. Maybe you could look at developer&#39;s tool, there should have some error log? What do they say?

Answer (score 0):

It should not send the request to main site, cause it works in curent site context. Did you check what exectely in "url" variable? Maybe there is a main site url?

Comment: the url : xyn.com/?es=subscribe

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this method and adding the following code to `.htaccess`.
I wanted all subdomains to have access.

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
   SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```